# X2JS remove attribute prefix

Tags: javascript, json, xml

I'm trying to convert some Xml to Json.
Using the X2JS this work ok, but I have a json object with properties prefixed with '_'
I don't want this, how can I remove it.
I've tried setting the attributePrefix to "" but that doesn't work.
Is there another way I can acheive this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's not supported by the reason. If you define it like '' it will be impossible to convert JSON to XML back. This prefix is using to differ XML attributes from elements.

PS. And the project now is living here https://github.com/abdmob/x2js

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this issues list here
https://code.google.com/p/x2js/issues/list
its listed as a requirement.

```
30  Defect  Accepted    Medium  ----    ----        Set a null prefix
```

which was accpeted, but I assume its not longer being supported.

Shame :(

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same concern, and looking at the code, it appears that prefix is defined this way :

```
config.attributePrefix = config.attributePrefix || "_";
```

So, a quick workaround is to set the prefix as an empty array (which will be evaluated to true as a boolean and to '' as a string).

```
var x2js = new X2JS({attributePrefix: []});
```

Note : of course, no back conversion is possible then.

Comment: @abdmob : IMHO it would make sense to allow a identical conversion : no prefixed attributes. The equivalent of a __toString method. Even if this prevent back-conversion...